# Is class definition not a static language feature in python?

Tags: javascript, python

I learnt that python is a dynamic language. For this, I mean, type(class) is assigned to name(symbol) at execution time.

```
""" In below statement,var becomes ref variable of var object which is of 
   class 'int' at execution time"""
var = 3
```

But i feel below code statically indicates that type  of name(`foo`)  is `Animal` class(subclass of `object` class) before executing statement `foo=Animal()`

```
class Animal(object):
    pass

foo = Animal()
```

where as in JavaScript below corresponding code would be about just creating an object without help of any class and i think JavaScript does not have a class hierarchy concept like python(saying `object` class is a parent of `str`/`int`/`dict`/`Animal` subclasses) , which is again a feel of static language.

```
var foo = {}
```

My question:

1)

Do you think python is a dynamic language?

2)

For JavaScript statement `var a = 3` & `var b = "hai"`, var is assigned a type `Number` and `String` in run time, Is `Number` & `String` something like `int` & `str` class in python?

3)

Does JavaScript assign a type to `foo` at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Both Python and Javascript are dynamic languages. It is not required that dynamic languages not have a type system; more characteristic of dynamic languages is that types are created at runtime instead of compile time. For example, the nearest Javascript equivalent of your given Python code would be

```
function Animal() {
    ;
}

var foo = new Animal()
```

which (very roughly speaking) creates a new type `Animal` and then creates an object of that type, just like the Python code. For comparison, the nearest Python equivalent of your given Javascript code would be

```
foo = object()
```

which makes a plain object and assigns it to `foo`.

As for your other questions, `Number` and `String` are analogous to `float` and `str` (though the differences between Javascript's primitive and reference types doesn't have a Python analogue), and Javascript assigns a type to the object referred to by `foo`, but not to the `foo` variable.

Comment: when you say foo = object() in javascript, does foo get a type in runtime? In python, for statement,  'foo = Animal()', type(foo) is Animal in run time rather i would say before execution time):

Comment: @Sham: `foo = object()` isn't valid Javascript. If you do `var foo = Object()` or `var foo = new Object()`, the type of the object is Object (or, pedantically speaking, `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === Object.prototype`).

Comment: is Object the parent class of all classes, what is the class hierarchy looks like in javascript?like in python, we have object class parent of int str and also parent of type class.

Comment: @Sham: Javascript doesn't have a class hierarchy. Since it uses prototypal inheritance, it has a prototype hierarchy. `Object.prototype` is sort of a quasi-root of the hierarchy; most objects have it in their prototype chain, but some don't, and primitives don't have prototypes at all.

Comment: Is prototypical inheritance an OOP paradigm?

Comment: As per the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) A prototype-based language, such as JavaScript, does not make this distinction: it simply has objects.----- On these lines, Do you think language like python having class concept is a static language  feature?

Comment: @Sham: No. Plenty of dynamic languages have classes. Don't assume that just because Javascript does things one way, languages that do things differently aren't dynamic.

Comment: Ok If plenty of dynamic languages have a class based OOP paradigm, Do these plenty of dynamic languages are dynamic languages?

Comment: @Sham: I have no idea what you were trying to ask with that sentence. Did you forget a word or something?

Comment: i mean class based OOP paradigm must be a static language feature not dynamic language feature.

Comment: @overexchange: It's not. I don't get why you keep saying that. It's really, really, not.

Comment: i feel class based OOPS paradigm is static language feature because we are defining the type at compile time. like 'class X x ;'

Comment: @overexchange: At compile time, there is no class. There is only code that will be executed at runtime to create a class. If we so choose, we can do `if blah: class Foo(Bar): ... else: class Foo(Baz): ...` It's exactly the same as with function definitions, and you don't call those a static feature, do you?